# Error using SHFileOperation() to copy a folder

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, copy, shfileoperation

I am trying to use `SHFileOperation()` to copy a folder, but get this error:

> a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "PCZZWSTR"

for both `s.pTo` and `s.pFrom`.

The code I'm using is:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
s.hwnd = hWnd;
s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;
s.pTo = "C:\\Users\\styler\\Desktop\\Folder1\0";
s.pFrom = "C:\\Users\\styler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\Folder3\\*\0";
SHFileOperation(&s);
```

What am I doing wrong in `s.pTo` and `s.pFrom`? I am setting those equal to the target folder and the source folder, but why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you are trying to assign `char` string literals to `wchar_t` string pointers (`PCZZWSTR` = `CONST WCHAR *`).  That means you must be compiling with `UNICODE` defined, where `SHFileOperation()` maps to `SHFileOperationW()` which expects `wchar_t*` string pointers instead of `char*` string pointers.

So, you need to prefix your string literals with the `L` prefix, eg:

```cpp
SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
s.hwnd = hWnd;
s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;
s.pTo = L"C:\\Users\\styler\\Desktop\\Folder1\0";
s.pFrom = L"C:\\Users\\styler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\Folder3\\*\0";
SHFileOperation(&s);
```

Or, since you are actually using the `TCHAR` version of `SHFileOperation()`, use the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro to match your string literals to the actual character type used by `TCHAR`:

```cpp
SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
s.hwnd = hWnd;
s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;
s.pTo = TEXT("C:\\Users\\styler\\Desktop\\Folder1\0");
s.pFrom = TEXT("C:\\Users\\styler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\Folder3\\*\0");
SHFileOperation(&s);
```

Comment: That got rid of the error, but for some reason the folder is not copying over to the location I specified.

Comment: That is a different issue.  What is the actual error code that `SHFileOperation()` returns? And does your app have permissions to access the folders in question?

Comment: It's saying "The file name you specified is not valid or too long. Specify a different file name."

Comment: That is not what I asked.  What is the ERROR CODE (the `int` value) that `SHFileOperation()` returns? `int errCode = SHFileOperation(&s);` What is the value of `errCode`? But in any case, did you validate that the ```C:\Users\styler\Desktop\Software\Folder2\Folder3\``` folder actually exists before trying to copy from it? Are you trying to copy the `Folder3` folder itself, or the files inside of it?

Comment: @SA1234 I read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shfileopstructw): "Standard MS-DOS wildcard characters, such as "*", are permitted only in the file-name position. Using a wildcard character elsewhere in the string will lead to unpredictable results."

Comment: @PaulSanders the wildcard IS being used in the file-name position only

Comment: @RemyLebeau Doesn't look that way to me.

Comment: @PaulSanders well, it is.  The `\0` after the wildcard doesn't change that. `pFrom` is a double-null-terminated list. The explicit `\0` terminates the 1st string in the list, and the implicit compiler-provided null terminator ends the list.  The `*` is in the file-name position of the 1st string of the list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I figured out what the issue was. I had switched the to and from folders. It is working now. Thank you so much!